# how to put a delay in this evaluate with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, automation, puppeteer, delay

I am trying to put a delay in this evaluate with puppeteer but I tried everything and didn't works, such as:

```js
await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
```

or with:

```js
setTimeout(() => { }, 1000);
```

```js
                await page.evaluate(() => {
                    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('button-text');
                    for (let element of elements) if (element.innerText == 'Add') element.click();
                })
```

I wanted it to be after every click like this example but it never works:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => {
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('button-text');
    for (let element of elements)
        if (element.innerText == 'Add'){
            await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
            element.click();   
        }
})
```

Comment: Everything in `page.evaluate` is serialized and executed in the browser process where it won't have access to `page`. You'd have to use a generic sleep inside the browser, e.g. `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000))`. What are you really trying to accomplish, though? I can write a more complete answer if you don't mind sharing the site you're scraping and the data you want to extract. The reason is that sleeping or waiting for timeouts is almost always a poor solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve because it causes a race condition. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do that outside of the browser context:

```
let elements = await page.$$eval('.button-text', els => els.filter(el => el.innerText === 'Add'))
for(let element of elements){
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000)
  await element.click()
}
```